# How to suspend a thread while its performing system call?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, pthreads

In Linux multi-threading (pthread), I want to asynchronously
suspend a thread while its performing a system call.

Imagine that there is a system call consisted with 100 assembly lines.
I want a thread to pause its execution inside kernel(syscall) at some
specific range of assembly codes(say, somewhere between line 20 ~ line 50). and later resume the thread from there(syscall instruction) whenever I want.

This doesn't have to be reliable.  If I have to try suspending - resuming the thread 10000 times and only one trial gives me what I want, its fine.

Can I use signals to achieve what I want?
I think signals will not be asynchronously handled when the target thread is inside kernel...

it would be really nice if I could get some advice about this issue.
thank you in advance.

Comment: `I think signals will not be asynchronously handled when the target thread is inside kernel.` - Yes, signals, received by the thread being inside kernel, are handled only upon returning to user space. You need to use kernel-related mechanisms for stop thread inside kernel. Aside from direct patching kernel code, it could be kprobes, KGDB, etc.